# Android: deleting the rows from database on click of a button

Tags: android, database

I am making an app in which i need that the rows that were inserted in the tables should get deleted on click of a button when the activity restarts.

I have tried the following approaches but  didnot get the desired result and the same rows get inserted again.

```
public void deleteDatabase(String databaseName) {
        context.deleteDatabase(databaseName);

    }
```

and

```
       public void deleteAll(){
           db.execSQL("TRUNCATE TABLE" +DATABASE_TABLE);
           db.execSQL("TRUNCATE TABLE" +DATABASE_TABLE_ICOn);
           db.execSQL("TRUNCATE TABLE" +DATABASE_TABLE_NAVIGATION);
           this.db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
           this.db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_NAVIGATION,null, null);
           this.db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_ICOn, null, null);
       }



      db = new WineDatabaseAdapter(HomePageWithPhoneIsOfflineDialog.this);

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your Phone is Offline")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Go Online",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int id1) {

                            if(WineDatabaseHelper.checkDataBase()==true){

                                db.deleteDatabase(WineDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
                                //db.deleteAll();
                            }
```

What shall i do to solve my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncate is not supported by Sqlite so its better to use DELETE

> The standard way to delete all the rows in a SQL

DELETE FROM MyTable

You can also execute [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) to compact the database when you are deleting lot of data and want to shrink the database file.

Comment: You can try this db.execSQL("Delete from table_name");

Comment: After deleting all rows from a table , you can reset the autoincrement (if needed) with DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='myTable'.

Comment: Hope your db instance is created by this db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Well, this works for me, there might be a silly problem in your case.

Comment: That is what i am asking for?

Comment: Please come to casual chat room so that we can discuss further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5053/discussion-between-ekjyot-and-lalit-poptani)